# Image SEO: Do more internal links improve ranking?

Tags: seo, google-image-search

**1. Let's say I use the same image (with the same path on my webspace) in several articles (instead of only one). Does this improve the rankings of the image?**

*Example*

The file `horses.png` is used in the articles `/animals`, `/pets`, `/horses`.

**2. If I want to use the same image in several articles is it better to save the image file under different filenames?**

*Example*

The file `animals-horses.png` is used in the article `/animals`.
The file `pets-horses.png` is used in the article `/pets`.
The file `horses.png` is used in the article `/horses`.

**Why I ask**

I think there is trade-off: The first example would rank `horses.png` higher than in the second example. But in the second example you get rankings under more keywords. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it better to save the image file under different filenames

no, redundancy is never good. Beside of file name there is hash value, allowing to identify an image. An the hash will be always the same, independently of path and file name. So it will be a kind of duplicated contet, which is just a bit harder to recognize.

Don't expect any additional rankings from the same file. Uniqueness and freshness are the keys to good rankings.

Comment: And what about my first question?

Comment: i think no. Otherwise, if you image gets external links - in this case i'm pretty sure, it will rank better.